# How to open and read video stream in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video, frame, video-processing

I wanted to open a video stream and get image frames from video

Current code:

```
oj = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo',1); 
frame = step(oj);
```

However I don't want a real time video. 
I want to  use a saved video file saved in a path. How should I rewrite this?

Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html

Comment: `imaq` is for real-time acquisition.  Use `VideoReader` as suggested by @brodroll.  I'll let brodoll write the answer if this does work for you - only fair!

Comment: Hi                                                                                                                         Will this be a solution??                                                                                                                                                                                                     obj = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4');                                                            video = read(obj);

Comment: Yes.  I've linked you to a duplicate post.  That has all the information you need.